# HttpClient 4.4 hangs on any request

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am having a problem where Apache HttpClieint 4.4 hangs on any request, even though a simple `java.net.URL`-based solution retrieves the same resource just fine.

Given the following HttpClient configuration:

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setExpectContinueEnabled(false)
        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.DEFAULT)
        .setRedirectsEnabled(false)
        .setSocketTimeout(5000)
        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
        .setStaleConnectionCheckEnabled(true)
        .build();

RegistryBuilder<ConnectionSocketFactory> connRegistryBuilder = RegistryBuilder.create();
connRegistryBuilder.register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.INSTANCE);
try { // Fixing: https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/issues/detail?id=174
    // By always trusting the ssl certificate
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean isTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {
                    return true;
                }
            }).build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslContext, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    connRegistryBuilder.register("https", sslsf);
} catch (KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    LOGGER.warn("Exception thrown while trying to register https");
    LOGGER.debug("Stacktrace", e);
}

Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> connRegistry = connRegistryBuilder.build();
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(connRegistry);
connectionManager.setMaxTotal(5);
connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5);

HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
clientBuilder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);
clientBuilder.setConnectionManager(connectionManager);
clientBuilder.setUserAgent("Cognitio");

HttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
```

Is there any good reason for the following HttpClient request to hang?

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://stackoverflow.com/");
request.setConfig(requestConfig);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

The following `java.net.URL` solution works no problem:

```
URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(inputLine);
in.close();
```

When I bombard my application with logging statements, I determine that it hangs at the `httpClient.execute` portion, and despite the timeouts specified, fails to timeout. Further, I'm using SLF4J with the JCL bridge, but I'm getting no log entries for `org.apache.http` when I set it to debug. Not sure if that's expected.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "When I bombard my application with logging statements" have you tried a debugger?

Comment: I've been running a debugger for a while, but as yet it hasn't helped me figure out what the problem is. Only that HttpClient is hanging somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by a little issue in `org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin`.

Namely, when you set `<includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>`, you get the plugin's SLF4J dependencies as well, and they cannot be excluded from what I can see. The simple way to get around this is to just declare your SLF4J/Logback dependencies first thing in your plugin dependencies section.

I found no need to declare slf4j-api again, just logback-classic and jcl-over-slf4j in my case.